# AddFontResource() slow on Win10 Anniversary Update

Tags: c#, windows, pinvoke

I'm working with maintenance of .NET 3.5 application. During application startup a number of fonts are read from working directory and registered in Windows. We use a pinvoke calls to `AddFontResource(string lpFileName)` (Gdi32.dll) for each font file.

The code has always been fast, that is until I upgraded to Win10 Anniversary Update (before that, there were no problems with Win10). Now a call can take half a second, which has increased startup time with 90 seconds.

Any idea what can cause the problem? And how to fix it?

Comment: The way I would go about investigating this is to create a brand new project that *just* calls `AddFontResource`, and see if it's still slow on Windows 10. Try it with the exact same fonts you're loading for your application, and then try it for different fonts. See if it's slow in both cases. Try to narrow down the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have also observed this problem, but in our case I found a solution: Call [AddFontResourceEx()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/windows/desktop/dd183327(v=vs.85).aspx).

The full change in our code was:

```
// from this
AddFontResource(pFont);

// to this
AddFontResourceEx(pFont, FR_PRIVATE, 0);
```

This solved the slowness problem in at least one of the machines I've personally tested.

Comment: Some tweaking was needed, but the method above worked perfectly.

<code>    
    private const uint FR_PRIVATE = 0x10;
    [DllImport("gdi32.dll")] static extern int AddFontResourceEx(string lpszFilename, 
    uint fl, IntPtr pdv);
    AddFontResourceEx("filename", FR_PRIVATE, IntPtr.Zero);
</code>

Answer (score 2):

Windows 10 anniversary update destroyed performance of the AddFontResource and RemoveFontResource APIs.  We're dealing with fallout from it at PortableApps.com now.  It's only an issue on Windows 10 after the anniversary update is applied.  It's so bad that my old slow ASUS T100 convertible runs code from a USB drive faster than my i7 desktop does from an internal SSD.

Comment: Ok. Always good to know it's not only on my machine this is a problem, thank's for the info John and @Marc Fauser.

Comment: If you can get a consistent repro on this problem, have you reported it to Microsoft? It doesn't do any good to suffer in silence.

Comment: I'd happily report it if Microsoft didn't make it impossible to report anything. It took me two tries to get a fix for a broken controller from Microsoft with the first rep charging me for accessories for something I didn't even own.